# Adding iOS app to Twitter accounts in settings??

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, social-framework

I am adding some sharing in my app to allow the use to post to FaceBook and to Twitter. I decided to use the Social Sharing framework as it does exactly what I need and works well.

However I noticed that my app doesn't ask the user for permission it assumes it has permission and does a check if there is an account setup.

The problem I see here is due to this - my app doesn't appear in the Settings - > Twitter under "Allow these apps to use your account" section.

Her is the code I use when I want to share an item - user taps on a `UIButton` which presents a UIActionSheet with various options"

```
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]){

            SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

            SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler completionBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){

                if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled){
                    NSLog (@"Cancelled");
                }else {
                    NSLog(@"Done");
                }

                [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            };

            controller.completionHandler = completionBlock;

            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.item.url];

            /* Adding the text to the Tweet */
            [controller setInitialText:@"Online now!"];
            [controller addURL:url];
            [controller addImage:self.imageView.image];

            [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else {
            [self showUserAlert:@"" message:@"Please make sure your FaceBook account has been setup on this device"
                       delegate:self
              cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay"];
    }
```

How do I ask for access first? And add the app to the settings part of iOS so the user can turn it on or off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need a permission because your app can't post without user action. User have all control.

You can check if sharing possible with `canSendTweet` method in `TWTweetComposeViewController`. Look up Xcode documentation. I'm sure Apple has something similar for Facebook.

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Twitter/Reference/TWTweetSheetViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: It seems that is the case. A Tweet or FaceBook post cannot go out without the user telling controlling it.

Just for reference: TWTweetComposeViewController has been deprecated since iOS6 its replacement is in the Social Framework: SLComposeViewController